# In Django how to convert an uploaded pdf file to an image file and save to the corresponding column in database?

Tags: python, django

I am creating an HTML template to show the cover of a pdf file(first page or user can choose one). I want Django to create the cover image automatically without extra upload.

The pdf file is uploaded using Django Modelform. Here is the structure of my code

models.py

```
class Pdffile(models.Model):
    pdf = models.FileField(upload_to='pdfdirectory/')
    filename = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    pagenumforcover = models.IntegerField()
    coverpage = models.FileField(upload_to='coverdirectory/')
```

form.py

```
class PdffileForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Pdffile
        fields = (
            'pdf',
            'filename',
            'pagenumforcover',
        )
```

views.py

```
def upload(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = PdffileForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('pdffilelist')
    else:
        form = PdffileForm()
    return render(request, "uploadform.html", {'form': form})


def pdfcover(request, pk):
    thispdf = get_object_or_404(Pdffile, pk=pk)

    return render(request, 'pdfcover.html', {'thispdf': thispdf})
```

In the 'pdfcover.html', I want to use the Django template language so I can render different HTML for different uploaded pdf files. That's why I want to save the image file to the same column as the pdf file.

I am new to Python, new to Django, and obviously new to stack overflow. I have tried pdf2image and PyPDF2 and I believe they all could work however I just cannot find the right code. If you guys enlighten me I will be thankful.

Comment: What image file format are you wanting the coverpage to in?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the `pdf2image` package there is a function called `convert_from_path`.

This is the description inside the package of what each of the parameters of the function does.

```
Parameters:
            pdf_path -> Path to the PDF that you want to convert
            dpi -> Image quality in DPI (default 200)
            output_folder -> Write the resulting images to a folder (instead of directly in memory)
            first_page -> First page to process
            last_page -> Last page to process before stopping
            fmt -> Output image format
            jpegopt -> jpeg options `quality`, `progressive`, and `optimize` (only for jpeg format)
            thread_count -> How many threads we are allowed to spawn for processing
            userpw -> PDF's password
            use_cropbox -> Use cropbox instead of mediabox
            strict -> When a Syntax Error is thrown, it will be raised as an Exception
            transparent -> Output with a transparent background instead of a white one.
            single_file -> Uses the -singlefile option from pdftoppm/pdftocairo
            output_file -> What is the output filename or generator
            poppler_path -> Path to look for poppler binaries
            grayscale -> Output grayscale image(s)
            size -> Size of the resulting image(s), uses the Pillow (width, height) standard
            paths_only -> Don't load image(s), return paths instead (requires output_folder)
            use_pdftocairo -> Use pdftocairo instead of pdftoppm, may help performance
            timeout -> Raise PDFPopplerTimeoutError after the given time
```

Because `convert_from_path` is designed to be able to turn every page in a pdf into an image the function returns an array of Image objects.

If you set the `output_folder` parameter each image will be saved to that location from the base directory. `output_folder` must be a full path in this case e.g. `'path/from/root/to/output_folder'`. If you don't set it the images won't be saved when converted, only in memory.

By default if you do not set the `output_file` parameter the function will generate a random formatted filename such as `0a15a918-59ba-4f15-90f0-2ed5fbd0c36c-1.ext`. Although if you do set a filename, because this filename is used for converting multiple pdf pages, if your `output_file` was `'file_name'` then each file would be named starting from `'file_name0001-1.ext'`.

Beware that if you set `output_file` and `output_folder` and try converting two different pdfs the second pdf will overwrite the image files of the first if they are in the same directory.

#### Here is some code modelled around yours in the question. This code assumes you have `pdf2image` installed.

I've added a built-in validator on the `pdf` FileField because else the code will crash if anything else but a pdf is uploaded.

```py
validators=[FileExtensionValidator(allowed_extensions=['pdf'])]
```

I also created three constants for the upload directories and file format. If you need to change any of them then the rest of the code can remain the same.

```py
COVER_PAGE_DIRECTORY = 'coverdirectory/'
PDF_DIRECTORY = 'pdfdirectory/'
COVER_PAGE_FORMAT = 'jpg'
```

Also I'm assuming you have the default settings setup for saving files.

`settings.py`

```py
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
```

`models.py`

```py
from django.core.validators import FileExtensionValidator
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from pdf2image import convert_from_path
from django.conf import settings
import os


COVER_PAGE_DIRECTORY = 'coverdirectory/'
PDF_DIRECTORY = 'pdfdirectory/'
COVER_PAGE_FORMAT = 'jpg'

# this function is used to rename the pdf to the name specified by filename field
def set_pdf_file_name(instance, filename):
    return os.path.join(PDF_DIRECTORY, '{}.pdf'.format(instance.filename))

# not used in this example
def set_cover_file_name(instance, filename):
    return os.path.join(COVER_PAGE_DIRECTORY, '{}.{}'.format(instance.filename, COVER_PAGE_FORMAT))

class Pdffile(models.Model):
    # validator checks file is pdf when form submitted
    pdf = models.FileField(
        upload_to=set_pdf_file_name, 
        validators=[FileExtensionValidator(allowed_extensions=['pdf'])]
        )
    filename = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    pagenumforcover = models.IntegerField()
    coverpage = models.FileField(upload_to=set_cover_file_name)

def convert_pdf_to_image(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        # check if COVER_PAGE_DIRECTORY exists, create it if it doesn't
        # have to do this because of setting coverpage attribute of instance programmatically
        cover_page_dir = os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_ROOT, COVER_PAGE_DIRECTORY)

        if not os.path.exists(cover_page_dir):
            os.mkdir(cover_page_dir)

        # convert page cover (in this case) to jpg and save
        cover_page_image = convert_from_path(
            pdf_path=instance.pdf.path,
            dpi=200, 
            first_page=instance.pagenumforcover, 
            last_page=instance.pagenumforcover, 
            fmt=COVER_PAGE_FORMAT, 
            output_folder=cover_page_dir,
            )[0]

        # get name of pdf_file 
        pdf_filename, extension = os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(instance.pdf.name))
        new_cover_page_path = '{}.{}'.format(os.path.join(cover_page_dir, pdf_filename), COVER_PAGE_FORMAT)
        # rename the file that was saved to be the same as the pdf file
        os.rename(cover_page_image.filename, new_cover_page_path)
        # get the relative path to the cover page to store in model
        new_cover_page_path_relative = '{}.{}'.format(os.path.join(COVER_PAGE_DIRECTORY, pdf_filename), COVER_PAGE_FORMAT)
        instance.coverpage = new_cover_page_path_relative

        # call save on the model instance to update database record
        instance.save()

post_save.connect(convert_pdf_to_image, sender=Pdffile)
```

`convert_pdf_to_image` is a function that runs on the `post_save` signal of the `Pdffile` model. It gets run after your `PdffileForm` gets saved in your upload view so that we can create the cover image file from the saved pdf file.

```py
cover_page_image = convert_from_path(
            pdf_path=instance.pdf.path,
            dpi=200, 
            first_page=instance.pagenumforcover, 
            last_page=instance.pagenumforcover, 
            fmt=COVER_PAGE_FORMAT, 
            output_folder=cover_page_dir,
            )[0]
```

Changing `dpi` will change the quality of the image. In order to only convert one page the `first_page` and `last_page` parameters are the same. Because the result is an array we grab the first and only element in the list inside `cover_page_image` in this case.

Minor change to your upload view.

`views.py`

```py
def upload(request):

    form = PdffileForm()

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = PdffileForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        # if form is not valid then form data will be sent back to view to show error message
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('pdffilelist')

    return render(request, "uploadform.html", {'form': form})
```

I don't know what your `upload.html` file looks like but I used the following which will work with the code provided.

`upload.html`

```html
<h1>Upload PDF</h1>

<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <button type="submit">Upload</button>
</form>
```

With an example pdf

[image: example pdf]

Uploaded through the form

[image: upload form]

The resulting database record

[image: db record]

The resulting file locations once uploaded

[image: file directory with images]

Final note:

Because FileFields have code to ensure that existing files don't get overwritten, The code

```py
# get name of pdf_file 
pdf_filename, extension = os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(instance.pdf.name))
new_cover_page_path = '{}.{}'.format(os.path.join(cover_page_dir, pdf_filename), COVER_PAGE_FORMAT)
# rename file to be the same as the pdf file
os.rename(cover_page_image.filename, new_cover_page_path)
# get the relative path to the cover page to store in model
new_cover_page_path_relative = '{}.{}'.format(os.path.join(COVER_PAGE_DIRECTORY, pdf_filename), COVER_PAGE_FORMAT)
instance.coverpage = new_cover_page_path_relative
```

ensures the pdf FileField filename is used to name the cover page because it is almost completely unique.

[image: duplicate filenames]

Comment: Hi, thank you for your great answer, with these codes I successfully generate the images, but during the coverpage rename process, I get an error says:PermissionError at /upload/
[WinError 32] The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process: 'media\\coverdirectory/b67ed10e-d3f0-4b35-a9fe-f4bf3aad439e-1.jpg' -> 'media\\coverdirectory/example.jpg'

Comment: After doing a little search, I add a line after the [0], cover_page_image.close(), which solve this problem.

Comment: interesting. Glad you were able to solve your problem!

Answer (score 0):

I used the explanation here, and everything works fine, except when from admin panel I oped the saved Pdffile object and try to change the pagenumforcover to another integer and then save it then it won't generate the new coverpage

Comment: no link shared but the answer suggest there should be